# django-facebook and renewing oauth token

Tags: facebook, oauth, django-facebook

I'm using [django-facebook](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook) on an app. Users can publish open graph actions from the application, but I'm running into problems with expired oauth tokens since moving away from offline_access.

I'd like to check token validity (and update it, if necessary) without a server-side, blocking, call.

My first thought was to pull the current access_token from the javascript library and then save to the database whenever they hit the page - but that overwrites the longer-term one with a 2 hr one; not very good.

Something more like what Facebook describes in [their blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/) could work, but, again, I'd like it to be non-blocking. Also, if the user is currently logged into the app, I'd like to not present them with a dialog just to renew the token.

django-facebook docs note that version 4 supports "Automatic reauthentication for expired tokens," but I don't seem to be triggering that in the app.

Either specifics on how to get this to happen automatically with django-facebook would be great, or, alternatively, some advice and guidance on standard/best practices here would be very helpful. Thanks!

(Apologies for any naïveté here, I'm an occasional FB developer and frequently find that I'm lagging behind changes to the Facebook API.)